# How to track my patent application

Tags: non-provisional, track

I submitted my patent application, got a uspto customer number, created a digital account and linked my patent number to the customer number, how and where do I now track the patent status online?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. I don't have an authoritative answer, but I think you use https://patentcenter.uspto.gov

Answer (score 1):

Until last week you could have used Private PAIR or PatentCenter. [Private PAIR was discontinued.](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/apply/checking-application-status/pair-announcements)